# How to copy specific text in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Example:

1.) Inside the text file (FileA)

```
Header1 You  can do everything
as long as you are determined
to work hard in your life 
End1
Header2
Honesty is the best policy
End2
```

Now, I want to copy the text from Header1 to End1. The output must only be:

```
Header1
You can do everything
as long as you are determined
to work hard in your life 
End1
```

Comment: Define `coy the text`? or if you need the first line only: `cat FileA|head -n1`

Comment: I mean, there could be multiple lines before Header1 gets End1.. So I'd like to know How can I get those characters from Header1 to End1.

Comment: Then please update your question, and add appropriate examples.. as per the one you've listed ,this is the solution. Also in your example you do not exclude the `Header1` and `End1` words, and it i not clear if you want those in your result or not.. as in the question you show the expected output, but in the comment you need the stuff `between` them ?

Comment: What is the reason of writing `Start`?

Comment: What is the requested output if there are multiple Header/End lines ?

Comment: @dash-o Header and End is always in pair in my end, and it is unique since it increments as you create another Header. 
Example: Header1 .... End1 ; Header2...End2 ; Header3...End3

But I am also curious about what if there'll be a lot of matching start and end word, how will we determine the one we needed. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk is rather useful parsing text files, try:

`awk '/Header1/,/End1/ { print }' FileA`

The will print the part of the file starting with **Header1** and ending with the first occurrence of **End1**

To save the output to a file (FileB in this case):

`awk '/Header1/,/End1/ { print }' FileA > FileB`

Comment: Wow.. Brilliant brother. This also works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Regex to match the WHOLE first segment: https://regex101.com/r/r9e7bB/1

```
$re = '/Header1.*End1/ms';
```

And if you want to match the inbetween only: https://regex101.com/r/r9e7bB/2

```
$re = '/Header1(.*)End1/ms';
```

or in shell, simply:

```
grep -zo "Header1.*End1" FileA
```